# How to retrieve email headers from email. Email And IMAPlib Python3

Tags: python-3.x, email, header, imaplib

guys.
I am trying to built an app that reads the email inbox and retrieves the emails from a certain address and the headers.
I can't figure out how to parse the headers, though. Please help.
Here is my code:

```
import imaplib, email
from email.parser import HeaderParser

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None, True)
def search(key, value, con):
    result, data = con.search(None, key, f'"{value}"')
    return data

def get_emails(result_bytes):
    msgs = []
    #print(result_bytes[0])
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        type, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msgs.append(data)
    return msgs

def get_filters(con):
    print("Choose a filter:")
    filters = con.list()
    print(filters)
    exit()



user = <REDACTED>
password = <REDACTED>
imap_url = "imap.gmail.com"
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)
con.select("INBOX")


result, data = con.fetch(b'1','(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
msgs = get_emails(search("FROM",<REDACTED>, con))
for m in msgs:
    print(get_body(email.message_from_bytes(m[0][1])))
```

I have tried looking up solutions on the internet but non seem to work for me. The truth is, I can't really understand the documentation of the email library that is provided. Any help is appriciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `email.message_from_bytes` is what you want, as shown in your `raw =` line.  What are you missing?

Comment: @Max. Thanks for replaying. Yes, I got the message in that way. But how do I get the address of the sender from this line? I couldn't find any method to achieve that. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage -> note \_\_getitem\_\_.  It works like a dictionary.  `message['From']`.  Assuming you're using a modern python, you probably want to use `message_from_bytes(..., policy=email.policy.default)` to get the new better parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll try out the solution and revert.

Comment: @Max Thanks a lot for your help! The solutions worked